# IIS (8) application Initialization versus a warm-up script

Tags: sharepoint-addin, iis, warm-up

Is the IIS (8) application Initialization really a better alternate then having a PowerShell script running as an scheduled task to keep the loading times down after an IISreset / server restart / application pool timeout ?

I'm looking into if this can replace a PowerShell script.

I have yet to find some really good arguments for using the IIS extension instead of a script. Are there any possible consequences of running the application initialization in a production environment? Could there be any impact to the performance?

The PowerShell cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` works great for warming up SharePoints HTML/CSS but we have some custom apps developed that still takes a very long time to load after an application pool has been restarted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We replaced the warmup script with IIS 8.0 Application Initialization in 2013 environment, we have no issue so far( more than 1 years). Rather, now we dont to worry if app pool recycled due to some other reasons.

> The IIS 8.0 Application Initialization feature enables website
>   administrators to configure IIS 8.0 to proactively perform
>   initialization tasks for one or more web applications. While an
>   application is being initialized, IIS 8.0 can also be configured to
>   return static content as a placeholder or "splash page" until an
>   application has completed its initialization tasks.
>
> The Application Initialization feature is configured through a
>   combination of global and application-specific rules that tell IIS 8.0
>   how and when to initialize web applications. The Application
>   Initialization feature also supports integration with the IIS Url
>   Rewrite Module to support more complex handling of placeholder content
>   while an application is still initializing.

[IIS 8.0 Application Initialization](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did you notice any extra performance? What i think about is that a script loops through all sites in a webapplication.. will this really give the same effect? Are you using overlapped process recycling?

Comment: Personally, i like it more than script. Since we enable it i did not see any issue. With script we had many issues...sometime schedule task unscheduled due to our security thing or account password change etc. Yes we are using the overlapped process.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Did you do this for all your web applications?

Comment: yes, we configured for all web applications only.

Comment: Last questions: Do you have any recommendations implementing this, or are there any certain pitfalls that i should be aware off?

Comment: MSFT give us that recommendations, No pitfall, straight fwd process.the link i shared exactly that's what we followed and so far fine.

Comment: Does it really only make requests over localhost? If so what are the hostname and initalizationPage settings for? Can i set the hostname with a custom host or ip address? will this override it trying to make requests over localhost? enter image description here

Does it work over SSL?

Does it work with authentication? Within the original Application Warm-Up implementation it looked as though you could specify auth credentials but i don't see how that is possible anymore.